# Reading from Excel csv into a matrix in VC++ and some error checking?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

Quick question: I have a csv file that contains 360 rows and 3 columns. Each cell or matrix entry is a type double (for example: 1.0000000, 0.9314933, 0.9866587). I was thinking the following code would get the entries:

```
//construct 2-d array 
 float CDF_inputs[360][3];

 std::ifstream file("filename");

for(int row = 0; row < 360; ++row)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);

    if ( !file.good() )
        break;

    std::stringstream iss(line);

    for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
    {
        std::string val;
        std::getline(iss, val, ',');

        if ( !iss.good() )
            break;

        std::stringstream convertor(val);
        convertor >> CDF_inputs[row][col];
    }
}
```

The file only contains doubles, no other characters (than the commas). I run the code, it builds (visual studio c++) and there are no errors. However I do not believe it is working correctly.

1. Is the given code correct?
2. How can I debug, or "print to console" either the array or an error message if the file is bad, or if the array fails to "load"?

Thanks first post for me.

Comment: *"However I do not believe it is working correctly."* Could you explain in the question: What exactly makes you believe that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are learning. Well, you can place breakpoint by hitting <kbd>F9</kbd> on a appropriate source code line and execute your code line-by-line by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> button. So, while debugging, you can hold mouse pointer on variables to see what they contain.

I have assumed that you are using Visual Studio.

Good Luck.